# Multiple conversion functions as "operator auto" in class

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, auto

In the following code

```
struct S {
    operator auto() { return 42; }
};
```

`operator auto` is equivalent to `operator int` since actual type would be deduced from the literal `42` and that type is `int`. If I write `42.5` instead of `42` then `operator auto` would be interpreted as `operator double` for obvious reason. But when I use both at the same time I got a compiler error for all three major compilers (gcc, clang, msvc):

```
struct S {
    operator auto() { return 42; }
    operator auto() { return 42.5; }
};
```

Actual error messages are vary among compilers, but the reason is the same: "Function already defined".

I can't find in standard why the both `operator auto` (with different return type) can't be used simultaneously in one class. Could someone point me to the standard's clause where that set of conversion functions considered as forbidden?

Comment: You could bypass the problems and the errors using templates and template specialization.

Comment: Something v.strange is going on see - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3cvMxacoG

Comment: http://wg21.link/cwg1670

Answer (score 1):

If you need just two or three `operator auto`s in a class, then the trick with `const` and `decltype(auto)` will work for you:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S 
{
    operator auto() { return 42; }
    operator const auto() { return 42.5; }
    operator decltype(auto)() { return 43.5f; }
};

int main()
{
   S s;
   std::cout << (int)s << '\n';
   std::cout << (double)s << '\n';
   std::cout << (float)s << '\n';
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hvbesaM4z

Unfortunately, it does not work for more than three distinct operators. It is the limitation of the current C++.

Answer (score 1):

Based on idea from Fedor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68312524/3240681) you can even use [at least 12 `auto` like operators](https://wandbox.org/permlink/irASvik33LY8hH8Q) with different qualifiers:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    operator auto() { return 42; }
    operator auto() const { return '+'; }
    operator auto() volatile { return 44LL; }
    operator const auto() { return 45.5; }
    operator const auto() const { return 46.5f; }
    operator const auto() volatile { return 47L; }    
    operator volatile auto() { return 48ULL; }
    operator volatile auto() const { return 49U; }
    operator volatile auto() volatile { return 50UL; }
    operator decltype(auto)() { return 51.5L; }
    operator decltype(auto)() const { return 52.5L; }
    operator decltype(auto)() volatile { return 53.5L; }
};

int main() {
    const S s;
    std::cout << (int)(S)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (char)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (long long)(volatile S)s << "\n";
    
    std::cout << (double)(S)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (float)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (long)(volatile S)s << "\n";
    
    std::cout << (unsigned long long)(S)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (unsigned)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (unsigned long)(volatile S)s << "\n";
    
    std::cout << (long double)(S)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (long double)s << "\n";
    std::cout << (long double)(volatile S)s << "\n";
}
```