# What is 'operator auto' in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

[Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and Visual Studio compilers (but not [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)) allow one to write the code as follows:

```
struct A
{
  operator auto() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   a.operator auto();
}
```

What is `operator auto`? Is it an extension of a particular compiler or a standard language feature and if yes in what language standard (e.g. C++17) did it appear?

Comment: Although you can't call it directly like that with GCC, it will accept `x = a;` or `x = a.operator int();`.

Comment: BTW there's [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67550830/3240681) with multiple `operator auto`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When `auto` is used in [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) the type will be deduced via return type deduction, i.e. `int` for this case (`0`). This was introduced in C++14.

> The placeholder auto can be used in *conversion-type-id*, indicating a
> [deduced return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction):
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     operator int(); // OK
>     operator auto() -> short;  // error: trailing return type not part of syntax
>     operator auto() const { return 10; } // OK: deduced return type
> };
> ```

Comment: g++ 10.2 prints `error: 'struct A' has no member named 'operator auto'`. Why?

Comment: This answers the main part of the question, but the most interesting part remains: what is the standard's take on the "name" of this function? Are Clang and VS correct in thinking that `a.operator auto()` is valid and `a.operator int()` is not, or is GCC (which does the opposite) right? Does the standard say anything about declaring two `operator auto`s (e.g. `operator auto() { return 0; } operator auto() { return 0.0; }`, which all compilers reject)?

Comment: Gcc seems to be right (to me); @eerorika posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267176/what-is-correct-syntax-for-explicit-call-to-conversion-operator-with-deduced-ret) about it.

Answer (score 27):

> What is operator auto in C++?
>
> ```
> operator auto() { return 0; }
> ```

`operator T` is a conversion operator to the type `T`. `auto` is a keyword for a placeholder type that will be deduced. When used as the return type, the type will be deducted from the return statement.

In this case, `auto` will be deduced to be `int` and thus it is an implicit conversion operator to `int`. It allows you to write for example:

```
A a;
int i = a;
```

> in what language standard (e.g. C++17) did it appear?

Conversion operators have been in the language since at least the first standard version. `auto` return type was introduced in C++14.

---

> ```
> a.operator auto();
> ```

Compilers seem to disagree how the operator could be called explicitly:

```
a.operator auto(); // Clang: OK,    GCC: ERROR
a.operator int();  // Clang: ERROR, GCC: OK
```

This may be under-specified in the language.

I don't think there's ever a reason to do such a call as you can use `static_cast` instead, so I would recommend avoiding it. Or if you prefer to use the call syntax, then don't use `auto`.

Comment: I created a follow-up question regarding the call syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68267176/2079303

Comment: _This may be under-specified in the language_ c++ is possibly the more specified language in history, with a standard of hundreds pages (if not thousands, I don't know) pages. Yet, there always space for something left under-specified. Not a complain, just a matter of fact; the standard is a great thing but also something that can never be perfect

Answer (score 6):

It's standard, from C++14, as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

In short, it means that the return type is determined, via type deduction, based on the return statement.

In other words, the three `auto`s in the following snippet trigger the same type deduction mechanism

```cpp
struct A
{
  auto operator()() { return 0; } // auto is the return type
  auto some_fun() { return 0; }   // auto is the return type
  operator auto() { return 0; }   // auto is not the return type
                                  // but it's deduced in the same way
};
```

Therefore, all requirements/limitations that you'd expect for other functions with `auto` return type also apply here, e.g. if more than one return statement is present, they should result in the same type being deduced, and so on.