# Conversion function template with a deduced return type

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, operator-keyword, auto

According to the standard [class.conv.fct#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.conv.fct#6):

> A conversion function template shall not have a deduced return type.

This prohibition appeared after [CWG1878](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1878.html), which was resolved almost 10 years ago.

Still, the latest releases of GCC 13, Clang 17 and MSVC 19.38 do accept conversion function template in certain circumstances, e.g.:

```
struct A {
    template<class=void>
    constexpr operator auto() const { return 1; }
};

constexpr int f() {
    return A{}.operator auto();
}

static_assert( f() == 1 );
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/addcfxh8o

The motivation of CWG1878 was that it "presents difficulties for some implementations". But since we see that at least 3 major implementations successfully supported conversion function template, is it still a valid justification for the prohibition? Probably there is a case that shows incompatibility of conversion function template with some other language feature?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266659/what-is-operator-auto-in-c